# passing parameters / session values between pages in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a `Login.jsp` page which has the `action="session.jsp"` set for a login form.

In the Login page, the session parameters are set as

```
<% String username = request.getParameter("username");
   session.setAttribute("username", username); %>
```

Now when I try to access these values in the session page

```
Welcome <%= session.getAttribute("username") %>
```

I get a `Welcome null`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is in the `Login.jsp`, there's no use in setting the session attribute there, if `username` is a field you're passing as parameter to the `session.jsp`. It will only be available as a parameter once `session.jsp` is invoked. Seeing some more code will help, if that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use <%=session.getAttribute("username").toString()%>